# manipulate string in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a variable list_name containing list of names separated by ':'

```
list_name=(rahul:john:steve) => list_name is of type 'string'
```

The list contains 1000s of names
Can't change the list_name because we get it from other department/company

want to write a query do to the purpose as shown below, but for that string manipualation would be required i.e. extracting the names from list_names based on the separator ':'

select roll_no from students
**where names is rahul or john or steve**   (problem part)

suggest to use some string manipulation technique in sql to extract the names from the string

PS: I am using proprietary sql and looping is not supported

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in standard'ish SQL using:

```
 select roll_no
 from students
 where concat(':', list_name, ':') like concat('%:', names, ':%')
```

In some databases, the where might be written as:

```
 where ':'+ list_name+':' like '%:'+names+':%'
```

or

```
 where ':'|| list_name||':' like '%:'||names||':%'
```

Comment: You have some extraneous parentheses in your 2nd and 3rd versions.

Comment: Don't you need to use `SUBSTR()` to skip over the surrounding `()` characters of `list_name`?

Comment: @Barmar . . . Extra parens were left by accident in the last two queries.  Either the whole expression would be surrounded or neither.  But, `substr()` is not needed, because the `like` just ignores them (they are part of the wildcard).

Comment: But when you do your concat, you'll have `':(rahul:john:steve):' LIKE '%:rahul:%'`, and it won't match.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Gosh, you are right, if the parentheses are in the string.  I understood them as syntax.  In that case, you definitely want to remove them before concatenating the colons.